# Solana program tests are not running in isolated environment

Tags: solana-program, rust, solana-program-test, bankclient

I am running tests with cargo test-sbf.
We have a Global Program State that needs to be created only once the lifetime of program.
All the program tests are isolated that means I have to do it in all the tests I have.
We changed nothing in our setup but now for some reason some of the tests are not running in a isolated setup and it returns error when we try to create global program state.

Comment: Can you provide more information? If nothing changed in your setup, then there's no potential causes to diagnose! For example, what versions of the Solana tools or packages are you using? Did you add anything into `tests/fixtures`? What error is being returned? Maybe there's a new bug in your program when creating the global state?

Comment: We are using Solana cli version `1.14.8` and in the test validator crate we use `1.15.2`. We process all the transaction with the help of `process_transaction_with_metadata` on bank client.

Comment: I have checked the code of the tests and instruction there is not bug. 
I feel it is with the test validator crate as that is something we update recently. Also We don't have it everytime it happens sometime in the CI and it has never failed locally for me or any other developer in our team

Comment: And can you add the error?

Comment: ```
failures:
---- should_fail_for_incorrect_late_interest_fee_percentage stdout ----
thread 'should_fail_for_incorrect_late_interest_fee_percentage' panicked at 'Failed to initialize ProgramState with default config: AccountInUse', /home/runner/work/credix-monorepo/credix-monorepo/packages/program/crates/credix-test-utils/src/lib.rs:407:14
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```

Comment: ProgramState is the account that needs to be created only once. 
The instruction and tests are correct as they locally work.

Comment: If you're getting `AccountInUse`, then the test environment isn't isolated, but the tests are. The tests are trying to recreate the account, but it's been previously created. So you can either totally isolate the tests with new instances of a test validator, or avoid recreating the Account on every test

Comment: yes, we are creating the new instance of `ProgramTest` again. So the test validator/bankclient is new for all. But I think they interfere sometime(randomly).
```
        let context = program_test.start_with_context().await;
```
also we are using `process_transaction_with_metadata` to send all transactions:
```
        testenv
            .program_test_context
            .banks_client
            .process_transaction_with_metadata(initialize_program_state_transaction)
            .await
```

Comment: We have around 400 tests written which all work fine locally every time. Every test with its own new instance of ProgramTestContext.

Comment: @JonC This still randomly happens. Do you have any idea?
Is there anything we should change?

Comment: Sometimes you just need to refresh the blockhash more often using `banks_client.get_new_latest_blockhash` and using that. I don't have too much else unfortunately!

Comment: Alright, Thanks for all the supports. we will downgrade to a lower solana version and if that does not work I will try to refreshing blockhashs. ❤️